# AVAudioPlayer memory leak

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have to play a whoosh sound in an iphone card game loop and I am using the below that still has a memory leak.
What else can be done to avoid the leak?

//  AVAudioPlayer ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
    NSAutoreleasePool *audioDataspool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; // pool is created
{
    NSString *soundpath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cardwhoosh" ofType:@"mp3"];

    NSData *audioData = [[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:soundpath]autorelease];

    AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithData:audioData error:NULL];

    soundpath   = nil;
    [soundpath release];

    [player play];//play sound

    player  = nil;
    [player release];
    [player autorelease];
    audioData   = nil;
    [audioData release];
}
    [audioDataspool release]; // all your autoreleased objects are released
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you understand memory management at all. Please read Apple's documentation or other tutorials on this subject for further help.

The below source code will work without leaks:

```
NSString *soundpath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cardwhoosh" ofType:@"mp3"]; /* autoreleased object */
NSData *audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:soundpath]; /* autoreleased object */
AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:audioData error:NULL]; /* contains init, so must be released */
[player play];
[player release], player = nil; /* Setting to nil is optional */
```

All the variables you have here are pointers. In Objective-C, all methods containing `init`, `create` and `copy` return objects that won't get autoreleased. In your case this means that only `player` needs to be released. This can either be done by sending it `autorelease`, it will then be thrown on the runloop's `NSAutoreleasePool` and released at the end of the runloop. Or you could release it immediately by sending `release`, which I've done above.

You're setting your variable to `nil` even before you've called `release`. This means that you're then calling a method on a `nil` pointer, which will do nothing. You don't have the pointer to the object anymore (it has just been overridden) causing a memory leak.

Comment: Thanks for your help. You are right I don't know much about memory management and I will read about it. When using your code it doesn't play the sound, only when I player = nil; first, but this doesn't prevent the leak, as you mentioned.

Comment: Please help me by writing the proper method to include autorelease on AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:audioData error:NULL]; so I could try the NSAutorelease runloop.

Comment: I now understand that the `AVAudioPlayer` will stop playing once it gets released (which is normal really, however I never thought of that). The best thing you can do is make `player` an instance variable and release it in `dealloc` so it will always get released. To save some memory you could also implement the delegate protocol to release the audio player when it has finished. I won't get into detail to that, please search for delegation and protocols.

Comment: I need to release it sooner than dealloc, since it plays every time a card is draw (a loop). I will try the delegate protocol. Thanks anyway JoostK!

Comment: You could easily use a instance variable. Then when you need to play a sound, you check whether `player` has been initialized before (search for: lazy loading) and initialize it when it doesn't, then calling `play` on the very same instance every time. This way you'll only need one `AVAudioPlayer` instance.

Comment: You are right an instance variable could be released in every cycle of the loop...I will try and let you know here. Thanks